# Defining Higher Order Functions Satisfying $f^n+g^n=1$

Tags: special-functions, trigonometric-integrals

I have spent some time thinking about the trigonometric identities $\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x=1$ and $\cosh^2 x-\sinh^2 x=1$. We use these functions to solve integrals with the terms $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ via a simple change of variable, using the derivative relationships between these functions.

I was wondering if there is a way to *define* new functions $f$ and $g$ that satisfy $[f(x)]^4+[g(x)]^4=1$, as well as analogous derivative relationships like $f'=g$ and $g'=-f$. If such functions could be defined, then I would imagine that solving integrals with terms like $\sqrt{1-x^4}$, etc. could be done in terms of these functions.

Attempting to do so gives me nonlinear ODE's like
$$(f')^4=1-f^4.$$
I was wondering if this has already been done, and if not, is what I am attempting to do reasonable? Can I define these function via these ODE's? I would appreciate references.

Edit: As was pointed out by Oscar Lanzi, the equations $f'=g$ and $g'=-f$ are inconsistent with the desired $f^4+g^4=1$. However, any "nice" choice of differential equations is ok (as I would like to make a simple change in variables in an integral); perhaps there is a different system of equations that are consistent with $f^4+g^4=1$?

Comment: A more topological than analytical idea: For $n=2$ with $f=\sin$ and $g=\cos$, you get a universal covering $(f,g)\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x^2+y^2=1\}$. For $n\neq 2$, you could analogously consider the continuous map $(f,g)\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow X_n=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x^n+y^n=1\}$.

Comment: Also for $n$ uneven, you have the factorization $f^n+g^n=(f+g)(f^{n-1}-f^{n-2}g+\ldots-fg^{n-2}+g^{n-1})=1$.

Comment: There are [$\cos_{p,q}(x),\sin_{p,q}(x)$](http://www.mat.ucm.es/congresos/c2iwit/abstracts_archivos/talkLang.pdf) functions satisfying $f^p+f^q=1$. Maybe these are one type of [Abelian function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelianFunction.html) satisfying this equation

Comment: @SamuelAdrianAntz I haven't learned topology yet (next semester!) but I don't see how what you wrote has simple derivative rules

Comment: There was a (now deleted) comment, that $f'=g$ and $g'=-f$ already yields, that $f$ and $g$ have to be linear combinations of $\sin$ and $\cos$. So if you are interested in $f^n+g^n=1$, you would have to drop or modify those conditions. The universal covering could help you get a factorization.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have $f'=g,g'=f$ and also $f^4+g^4=1$. For the differential equations imply

$f''=-f$ — eliminate $g$

$g(df/dg)=-f$ — reintroduce $g=f'$ for the autonomous equation

$f^{\color{blue}{2}}+g^{\color{blue}{2}}=C$ — separate and integrate

You're stuck with the exponent $2$.

Comment: The choice of differential equations was rather arbitrary; I would like it to have a nice form that will allow a simple change in variable. I will try to see if I can write a proper system that will give me the desired $f^4+g^4=1$